# Tkinter Printing an error code to a label from a function

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm experimenting with Tkinter and MySQL in python, and I've hit a snag I can't work out. All of my Tkinter code is encased in classes, and I have a function that is called that will go off and insert a new row into a MySQL table. What I want is for there to be a message displayed in a label once this operation is complete or encounters an error.

Here is the button that calls the function, It is inside a class called "LandingPage":

```
# Button to take all the user input in the entry boxes and send it to
# the addClientToDB() function that will insert them into the database.
btnAddClient = ttk.Button(addClient, text="Add Client",
                              command=lambda:addClientToDB(self, tbContactName.get(), tbEmailAddr.get(), tbClientCompany.get()))
# Adding the button to the grid at 3, 1, and having it span 2 columns.
# Giving it 15px padding in x and 5px in y
btnAddClient.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=5)
```

And here is the code that it calls:

```
    # Function for adding clients to the database. It needs the name of the person,
    # the email address and the company to be parsed to it
    def addClientToDB(self, name, emailAddr, company):
        # Creating the Connection string for the INSERT INTO statement, and adding
        # the values to the end of the statement
        cnxString = "INSERT INTO clientDetails(contactName, emailAddr, clientCompany)" \
        "VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"
        # Adding the arguments to a list that will also be sent
        args = (name, emailAddr, company)

        # Sending the string and the arguments off to the sendSqlQuery(), and
        # putting anything that was returned into the "ans" variable
        ans = sendSqlQuery(cnxString, args)

        lblErrorCode.config(text=ans)
        # Printing anything that was returned to the console for debugging purposes
        print(ans)
```

Obviously, you can see in that code that I'm trying to set the label "lblErrorCode" using the .config() method, but when I run the code, nothing happens. The Data is inserted, but nothing is happening to the Label. I do however get output to the terminal. So, as a test, I have deliberately deliberately tried to enter a string that is too long, which results in this to the terminal, but nothing to the Label:

```
1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'contactName' at row 1
```

Any Ideas of how to get the function to update the label?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: What you are doing looks correct. Are you certain the label widget is on screen?

Comment: Yep, I have it added to the grid:
    lblErrorCode = ttk.Label(addClient, text="")
    lblErrorCode.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=5)

Comment: Have you _verified_ that it is visible? Have you tried initializing the message to something so that you're absolutely certain it's visible? Without a proper [mcve] we're probably not going to be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, it is Visible, I have set the text to "Hello World", and it is visible